# How to suppress RSpec output "Run options: include {:focus=>true}"?

Tags: rspec

Every time the specs run, RSpec prints `Run options: include {:focus=>true}`.

I already know what the run options are, so is there a way to suppress this output?

Comment: @LandonSchropp Currently this message is always displayed if at least one filter is provided and there is no way to disable it: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/229bbaa1093aeba3e7c9c02eb9fc82fb36d5c2a3/lib/rspec/core/world.rb#L107-L113. As a hacky workaround you could create your own formatter which would filter out the messages starting with "Run options" and use your formatter instead of the default one.

Comment: @nemesv That's a bummer, but thanks for the comment.

Comment: I opened an issue in rspec-core for this topic. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1896

Answer (score 7):

There is now an [option for silencing those filter messages](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Filtering.md#silencing-filter-announcements) if you set `config.silence_filter_announcements = true` like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_including :foo => :bar
  c.silence_filter_announcements = true
end
```